# Cannot reference object using TypeScript and Require.JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, amd

I have a TypeScript project. Basically I have a file called `myId.ts`:

```
export module MyModule {
    export class MyId {
        constructor() { ... }
        public compareTo(other: MyId): number { ... }
        public toString(): string { ... }
    }
}
```

I have a `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "module": "amd",
        "outDir": "./out"
    },
    "files": [
        "myId.ts"
    ]
}
```

I compile this thing using this command:

```
tsc --project .
```

Where the current directory contains the configuration file ad also the source file.

Well, when compiling everything is fine, I get `out/myId.js`:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    var MyModule;
    (function (MyModule) {
        var MyId = (function () {
            function MyId() { ... }
            MyId.prototype.compareTo = function (other) { ... };
            MyId.prototype.toString = function () { ... };
        })();
        MyModule.MyId = MyId;
    })(MyModule = exports.MyModule || (exports.MyModule = {}));
});
```

### Problems referencing `MyId`

Well, I want to use this in a web page and call it from using JavaScript, so by following [Require.JS guidelines](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html), I create my web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EVT Example - Minimal</title>
    <script src="./require.js" type="text/javascript" data-main="./myId"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

However, when I open the inspector (F12 tools) and try referencing `MyModule.MyId`, nothing can be found! How can I reference my type?

#### Everything loaded fine

The inspector told me that `myId.js` has been successfully loaded actually. So it is not a problem concerning the fact that Require.JS did not load the script.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I open the inspector (F12 tools) and try referencing MyModule.MyId, nothing can be found! How can I reference my type

Modules are not global and *that is a good thing*. So if you type `MyModule.MyId` nothing will happen.

If you want to access it on the console *you can put it on window* e.g.:

```
export module MyModule {
    export class MyId {
        constructor() { ... }
        public compareTo(other: MyId): number { ... }
        public toString(): string { ... }
    }
}
(window as any).MyModule = MyModule;
```

Then you can do `MyModule.MyId` in the console. Of course there is *only one global space* and its an awful idea to start polluting it (kills the purpose of modular maintainable JavaScript). Its okay to do it for testing

Comment: I see... That is nice. However I have a question... Where does actually require.js put all the stuff? If not in the window object, where?

Comment: In a function wrapped by a `define` call. The top level `define` is called by `data-main` 

Comment: Is `as` allowed in TypeScript?

Comment: `as` is for type assertion. See https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html